# Brush and transition coexist

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with d3.js and I have a problem. I have a graph in which I use the brush function to resize the scale of the axes.

When I do the brush, I call the function `updateChart`:

```
var brush = d3.brush()                
    .extent( [ [0,0], [width,height] ] ) 
    .on("end", updateChart)
```

Where the `updateChart` function is:

```
function updateChart() {
        extent = d3.event.selection

        if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, 350); 
             x = d3.scaleTime()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { 
                return new Date(d.valueX);}))
                .rangeRound([0, width]);

                y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([d3.min(data, function(d){return d.valueY;}), 
                        d3.max(data, function(d){return d.valueY;})])
                .range([ height, 0]);


        }else{
            x.domain([ x.invert(extent[0][0]), x.invert(extent[1][0]) ])
            y.domain([ y.invert(extent[1][1]), y.invert(extent[0][1]) ])
            scatter.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null) // This remove the grey brush area as soon as the selection has been done
        }

        // Update axis and circle position
        xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(multiFormat));
        yAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisLeft(y))

        scatter
        .selectAll("circle")
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attr("cx",function(d) {return x(new Date(d.valueX))} )
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.valueY); } )

    }
```

I also have a function so that when I put the mouse on a circle it shows me information.

```
area.on("mouseover", highlight)

var highlight = function(d) {
            var selected_specie = d.Group
            d3.selectAll(".dot")
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("fill", "lightgrey")
            .attr("r", 3)

            d3.selectAll("." + selected_specie)
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("fill", color(selected_specie))
            .attr("r", 7)
            var x = (d3.event.pageX - document.getElementById('chartZone').getBoundingClientRect().x + 60);
            var y = (d3.event.pageY - 120);

            tooltip
            .html("Valor exacto X: " + d.valueX + " Y: " + d.valueY + " <br> en  " + d.Group)
            .style("width","100px")
            .style("position","absolute")
            .style("left", x +"px") 
            .style("top", y +"px")
            .style("opacity", 1)
        }
```

The problem is: when I put the mouse over a circle, the transition finishes.
The mouseover function doesnt allow you to finish the transition correctly.

Is there any way to stop listening mouse events while I have a transition?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To stop the events can be done with the following code:

```js
var brush = d3.brush()                 // Add the brush feature using the d3.brush function
 .extent( [ [0,0], [width,height] ] ) // initialise the brush area: start at 0,0 and finishes at width,height: it means I select the whole graph area
 .on("start", function () {(scatter.attr("pointer-events","none"))})
 .on("end", updateChart)
```

This way you can stop the events when the brush starts. Within the updateChart function, at the end you have to start it again:

```
setTimeout(function (){scatter.attr("pointer-events","all");},1001);
```

This worked for me.